# Get and display category options to posts on WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a blog index page which simply show all posts under the taxonomy `resources`.

There are several `categories` defined under `resources`. For experimental purposes, blog post with the title `sample post` has the categories `article` and `eGuide` assigned to it.

I'm trying to get the categories to display within a `ul` (a new `li` is generated for each `category`), but `get_the_category` doesn't seem to render anything.

**I have the following markup:**

```
<?php
global $post;
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <div class="card">
        <div class="categories">
            <?php get_the_category($post->ID); ?>
            <?php //the_tags('<ul><li>','</li><li>','</li></ul>'); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php
endwhile; 
wp_reset_query(); 
?>
```

As you can see, my previous approach was via tags (`the_tags`), which worked (a new `li` was generated for each tag). However, with `get_the_category`, I can't even get the categories to appear.

Comment: are you using a default category or custom taxonomy? your post is confusing, you're mixing a taxonomy with category

Comment: _“but get_the_category doesn't seem to render anything”_ - this function does not produce any output, it _returns_ an array of WP_Term objects. _You_ need to loop over that array, and output the relevant data from the items yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You could try `get_the_category_list()` function which will display post categories in unordered list by default:

```
<?php
global $post;
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <div class="card">
        <div class="categories">
            <?php echo get_the_category_list(); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php
endwhile; 
wp_reset_query(); 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Managed to resolve it after `misorude`'s loop comment.

**Solution:**

```
<ul>
    <?php 
    foreach(get_the_category() as $category){
       echo '
               <li>
                  <a href="'.get_category_link($category->cat_ID).'">'.$category->cat_name.'</a>
               </li>
            ';
    }
    ?>
```